# Парсер на php как взять текст

Tags: php, парсер

Всем привет! Есть страница: 
https://www.betexplorer.com/hockey/russia/mhl/irbis-mhl-belye-medvedi-mhl/KGRB3hzk/ 
Как спарсить информацию из блока "Show H2H matches", который в самом низу
Этот блок
Show H2H matches

Можно как-то при парсинге сначала как бы нажать на этот блок, показать инфу и уже ее взять?

Comment: Конечно можно запарсить указанный контент, однако это не  через `PHP` Вам нужно написать расширение, используя `Javascript`, для браузера(например для Google Chrome) и через это расширение получить доступ ко всему на открытой странице.  В расширении можете написать алгоритм для парсинга, который начинается с нажатием на кнопку....

Comment: Не очень понятно пока... Может возможно вместо нажатия на этот блок узнать как он подгрузился (откуда) и уже оттуда же и парсить? Ну, скажем, вместо функции ЯВЫ, которая сейчас - узнать, куда передаются данные(какие) и получить ответ вместо этого сразу оттуда?

Comment: если данных на странице нет, а они вдруг появляются при клике, значит их запрашивают аяксом. Откройте окно сетевой активности в инструментах браузера и кликайте на свою ссылку. Увидите аякс запрос. Изучите, постоянные там параметры или нет. Если постоянные, то просто выполняйте этот самый запрос в пхп. Если параметры меняются, то скорее всего их значения можно выдрать из других мест этой страницы.

Comment: @Андрей  Такой алгоритм может сработать, только если разработчики данного сайта "чайники" и у них нет какой-либо защиты от внешних запросов. В основном всегда у таких ресурсов есть защита от внешних запросов и вы не сможете получить данные, даже если будете обращаться к нужному файлу с нужными параметрами. По этой причине советую помостреть в сторону расширений для браузера, при таком раскладе вы сможете через `js` делать всё что хотите а для сайта это будут запросы, как бы делал простой посетитель.

Comment: @Arsen предложите-ка вариант защиты от запросов, которые на сайте аяксом тянутся. интересно послушать. Расширения браузера мало кому интересны тут, человеку похоже задачу надо автоматизировать на стороне вэб-приложения,а не у клиента.

Comment: @teran есть несколько методов, как пример использование CSRF, но я люблю когда алгоритм проверяет по нескольким параметрам(чем больше, тем лучше), в том числе и по заголовкам(на счёт подмены знаю, но мы тоже не лыком сшиты :) ), Origin  и т.д.   На счёт  -  **на стороне вэб-приложения**  я не спорю, предлагаю альтернативу т.к детально автор не просветил, что будет делать с этими данными, с какой частотой должны быть обновления и т.д ))

Comment: @Arsen csrf вообще мимо. значение токена так или иначе будет присутствовать на странице. Если пишем парсер страницы, то и его выдернем.

Comment: @teran а почему мимо?  )) Конечно же речь не идёт о токене, который находится на странице :)  можно создавать уникальный, разовый токен во время запроса, можно сохранить токен в куках, и как вы собираетесь взять её на стороне вэб-приложения ?

Comment: мне надо просто спарсить данные по личным встречам ОДИН раз - и всё! Спарсю, запишу их в БД и всё! просто матчей такого вида много....принцип один везде

Comment: ну аякс выдает это по нажатии:

Comment: https://www.betexplorer.com/gres/ajax/mutual-matches.php?par=NCwwLElWMGVuUHJiLFlSMjRlNTVl

Comment: Но страница пустая....хм...

Comment: @Arsen можно подумать куки в заголовках запроса не путешествуют.

Comment: @teran да, конечно летят с запросом, я имел ввиду LocalStorage, дурацкая привычка их тоже называть "кукой" ))

Comment: @Arsen да в любом случае, это значение будет где-то на странице.